# Copy PropertySheet Information to Another Dialog Box

Tags: visual-c++, propertysheet

I want to load information from propertySheet and display to another dialog box in VC++, anyone know how to do is ?

Thanks!

Comment: Show us what you tried; otherwise people will think you're asking for code...

Comment: I don't have any idea. So I don't know how to do this.